# Modify injected service on event from another service

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I have the following problem:

I have `2` services:
 `Sa` 
 `Sb`.
In order for the user to be able to use `sb` he needs to perform an action in `Sa` which will grant him a `token`.
He will then use this `token` for all actions that he will perform on `Sb`.
I do not want all methods of `Sb` to need the `token` as an argument.I want to inject the `Sb` in the `servicecollection` from the start ,and be able to store this `token` as an inner property (after the user uses `Sa`),

How can i do this? How can i alter an injected service based on an action in another service.

**Service that grants token**

```
public class Sa{
    //grants token
    public string GrantToken(string username);
}
```

**Service with set-able property on event**

```
public class Sb{
    private internalService internalService;
    public ClassName(InternalService internalService)
    {
        this.internalService=internalService;
    }
    public string Token{get;set;}


    ///all these actions would  need the user to provide the token as parameter
    /// i want to somehow set the `Token` property of Sb after the Sa grants the token
    public void Action1(/*string token */){
        this.internalService.DoAction1(Token);

    }
    public void Action2(/*string token */){
        this.internalService.DoAction2(Token);
    }
    public void ActionN(){
        this.internalService.DoActionN(Token);
    }
}


//internal service that needs the token
public class InternalService
{
    public void DoAction1(string token);
    public void DoAction2(string token);
    //.....//
    public void DoActionN(string token);
}
`
```

**Startup**

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    Sa sa=new Sa();
    Sb sb=new Sb(); //i want this injected from the get-go but to have the `Token` property set-able 
    InternalService ins=new InternalService();
    services.AddSingleton(ins);
    services.AddTransient(sa);
    services.AddTransient(sb);
}
```

**Scenario**

//we are in a class that has inside it both an Sa and an Sb

```
var token=sa.GrantToken(); 
//i want now this token to be passed to Sb so i can then call its actions //without the need of the token
var result1=sb.Action1();
var result2=sb.Action2();
......
var resultN=sb.ActionN(); //<--
```

Comment: you would need a sb factory that creates the instance using the token created from  sa

Comment: That or let the token be set on sb before invoking dependent members

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already were mentioned in the comments you could create a factory class, which will be responsible for creating instance of `Sb` based on the granted token by `Sa`.

```
public interface ISbFactory
{
    Sb Create();
}

public class SbFactory : ISbFactory
{
    private readonly Sa _sa;

    public SbFactory(Sa sa) => _sa = sa;

    public Sb Create()
    {
        var token = _sa.GrantToken();
        return new Sb(token);
    }
}
```

Usage

```
public class ConsumerOfSb
{
    private readonly ISbFactory _sbFactory;

    public ConsumerOfSb(ISbFactory sbFactory) => _sbFactory = sbFactory;

    public void Execute()
    {
        var sb = _sbFactory.Create();
        sb.ExecuteActionOne();
    }
}
```

Another approach: ASP.NET dependency injection provide overload methods with "factory action". So you can register a function which will be called every time `Sb` instance required as a dependency.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) 
{
    services.AddTransient(sa);
    services.AddTransient<Sb>(provider =>
    {
        var sa = provider.GetRequiredService<Sa>();
        var token = sa.GrantToken();
        return new Sb(token);
    });
}
```

With this approach consumer of `Sb` don't need to have dependency on the factory.

Comment: Like the factory delegate approach. Good suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can add another abstraction here - abstract factory for Sb e.g.

```
    public interface ISbFactory
    {
        SbFactory Create(string token);
    }
```

Client classes which now have dependencies on Sb should change it to ISbFactory. With such approach you put responsible for setting token to factory instead of modifying already created service.

Comment: That mean all classes which uses `ISbFactory` need to have dependency on `Sa` to retrieve a token for creating `Sb` instance.

Comment: Yes, in this implementation. You can always change nomenclature to Create() and inject Sa into factory implementation. In this way you encapsulate logic of creating token. However, right choice depends on problem details.